# How to start a blockchain wallet service automatically?

Tags: php, blockchain.info-api

Writting

```
sudo blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000
```

on the command line will start the local service, but I ca not find out how to run it forever. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I am searching for but I can't find anything.
Currently, I am starting the service using exec() every time I make an API call as follow. I know it's not recommended though.

```
  <?php
  // start blockchain services
  exec("/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/service blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000");
  ?>
```